# vega condition test on datum['key'] when value is itself a {key:value} object

Tags: predicate, vega-lite, vega

Using the Vega-Lite JSON specification of the scatterplot example ( https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/point_2d.html ), and a cars.json  altered to add an annotation field:

```
[
   {
      "annotation": {"selected" : true},
      "Name":"chevrolet chevelle malibu",
      "Miles_per_Gallon":18,
      "Horsepower":130,
   },
   {
      "annotation": {"selected": false},
      "Name":"buick skylark 320",
      "Horsepower": 165
   }
]
```

I want to do a conditional color encoding with a test on that boolean annotation.selected value . Using javascript dot notation seems straightforward:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A scatterplot showing horsepower and miles per gallons for various cars.",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"
        color: {
            condition: {
                "test": "datum['annotation'].selected === true",
                value: 'yellow'
            },
            value: 'steelblue'
        }
    }
}
```

But no joy.

I was hoping the malibu would plot yellow and the skylark blue.  But the above test predicate form and variants evaluate to false, and both points plot blue.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you supply a full spec and clarify your desired outcome? It is important to say whether this is Vega or VL

Comment: How about just `"test": "datum['annotation'].selected"`?

Comment: I edited the question to supply the full spec for that Vega-Lite example

Comment: In fact `"test": "datum['annotation'].selected === true"`  does work.

Comment: `"test": "datum['annotation'].selected"`  is returning truthy for `annotation: {selected: true}`  but also other non-null values including `annotation: {selected: "anystring"}` .  Hence use the `===` for an exact comparison with the accessed value.